# PHP unzip and strip leading map using ZipArchive

Tags: php, unzip, php-ziparchive

Does anyone know if it's possible to unzip a file in PHP using ZipArchive, and to strip the leading map (similar to using TAR's --strip parameter)?

Thank you

Comment: You mean `--strip-components` from tar? I think there's no vanilla `--strip`.

Comment: According to the man page on my system tar don't have that, however the binary itself responds to it and it seems to be the same thing.